# Stack level too deep, something better than read_attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a module that has virtual attributes for some of my models. Now, i know why i get a stack too deep error and that i can use read_attribute with that.

However, i don't really like the idea of having read_attribute methods inside my getters/setters. I think it makes the code a bit more unreadable. Is there another, prettier way to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for cleaner code, you can use `self[:attr]` instead of `read/write_attribute(:attr)`:

```
def bar
  self[:bar].reverse
end

def bar=(new_bar)
  self[:bar] = new_bar.upcase
end
```

Comment: @Dan Its working but why simply bar.reverse is not working in getter methor? I'm not getting it clearly; Will you please explain, Thanks in advance :)